# adapting proof to show interval connected

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

I've read and understand the proof I've attached here proving [a,b] is connected. The notes then say that is can easily be adapted to open, half open, and unbounded intervals. How would I adapt it for them. For the unbounded one (for example the reals) I can't use the supremum argument, and for the open one, say (a,b), we can't assume 'a' is in C like before. Would we need to take a point in between, say, (a+b)/2, and then work in both directions instead, or is there a better way? How do we get around that?[image: attached notes]

Answer (score 1):

Let $I$ be an interval and $I\subset U\cup V$ with $U,V$ open, $U\cap I\ne\emptyset$, $V\cap I\ne \emptyset$. We want to show that this implies $U\cap V\cap I\ne\emptyset$.
Pick $a\in U\cap I$, $b\in V\cap I$. We may assume without loss of generality that  $a\le b$. As we already know that $[a,b]$ is connected, it follows that $U\cap V\cap [a,b]\ne\emptyset$, say $c\in U\cap V\cap [a,b]$. Then also $c\in U\cap V\cap I$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I'm struggling to see/prove U∩V∩I≠∅ shows I is connected. Also would this not work for I=R, because then there are no such U,V?

Comment: on a completely different note, can't we find a homeomorphism from (a,b), say (0,1) to any open / half open interval, so all we really need to show is that it works for any open interval